# What does " Value of tuple type '(String, JSON)' has no member 'subscript' " refer to in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, alamofire, swifty-json

So for my file I am trying to use Alamofire to make a request in order to get Photos from Flickr using their API.

I am using CoreData, Alamofire, and SwiftyJSON

The method is as follow:

```
func getImagesFromFlickr(_ selectedPin: Pin, _ page: Int, _ completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: [Photo]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    /* Set Parameters */
    let methodParameters: [String:String] = [
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Method: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.SearchMethod,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.APIKey: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.APIKey,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.BoundingBox: bboxString(longitude:selectedPin.longitude , latitude: selectedPin.latitude),
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Latitude: "\(selectedPin.latitude)",
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Longitude: "\(selectedPin.longitude)",
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.PerPage: "21",
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Page: "\(page)",
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.SafeSearch: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.UseSafeSearch,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Extras: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.MediumURL,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.Format: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.ResponseFormat,
        Constants.FlickrParameterKeys.NoJSONCallback: Constants.FlickrParameterValues.DisableJSONCallback
    ]

    /* Build the URL */
    let url = flickrURLFromParameters(methodParameters)

    /* Make the request with Alamofire */
    Alamofire.request(url).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Success! Got the Images from Flickr!")
            let flickrJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(flickrJSON)
            let photosDict = flickrJSON["photos"]
            let photoArray = photosDict["photo"]

            performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                let context = CoreDataStack.getContext()

                var imageUrlString = [Photo]()

                for url in photoArray {
                    let urlString = String(url[Constants.FlickrResponseKeys.MediumURL])

                    let photo : Photo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Photo", into: context ) as! Photo

                    photo.urlString = urlString
                    photo.pin = selectedPin
                    imageUrlString.append(photo)
                    CoreDataStack.saveContext()
                }
                completionHandler(imageUrlString, nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
        }
    }
}
```

The error is within this line of code:

`let urlString = String(url[Constants.FlickrResponseKeys.MediumURL])`

I get this error in Xcode saying " **Value of tuple type '(String, JSON)' has no member 'subscript'** "

Any help with why I am getting this error is much appreciated.
Also, any recommendations on how I can implement this method better is much appreciated.

If you would like to take a look at my project it is under the branch called "Networking-with-Alamofire"

The link is here:
https://github.com/RobertoEfrainHernandez/Virtual-Tourist-Udacity/tree/Networking-with-Alamofire

If you look under the master branch I did my networking code using URLSessions and my goal for the Networking-with-Alamofire branch was to convert those networking methods using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

Comment: I guess you should be looking at the content of each url you get in the photoArray loop. You are trying to use it with a subscript (Constants.FlickrResponseKeys.MediumURL), and it looks like that is not possible with url.

Answer (score 0):

```
for url in photoArray
```

I suppose here `url` not always a dictionary, in your case you get a tuple (value1, value2) and obviously you cannot access parameters in tuple via subscript syntax.

You need to check JSON response and make some adjustments in mapping func